# Jquery - update textbox with value from another textbox in runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have 2 text boxes: `textbox 1` and `textbox2`. When I insert value in `textbox1` then i want to show the product of current page form field * `textbox1` in `texboxt2` automatically. Is there any way in jquery?

Comment: you should add some code

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this to your page's javascript code:

```
$("#textbox1").change(function(){
    $("#textbox2").val($("#textbox1").val());
});
```

Comment: Thank You So Much